# PowerShell remote call. Access is denied from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, exchange-server

i write a code for remote access for exchange powershell from asp.net application to enable remote mail using vb.net and exchange 2016 the command run successfully from my visual studio debug but when i put in iis web server it's giving me

> Access is denied

i added user to server admins / local administrtors and even orgnization admins  aslo i change the application pool to be a server admin user 
and still get the same error in webserver

this is the code

```
string back = "";
            try
            {
                string ServerUri = "http://{server}/PowerShell/";
                //use one of CAS servers
                string SchemaUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";
                string userName = AccountOperatorLogon;
                //user must be member of "Recipient Management" group to create Mailboxes
                System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
                foreach (char x in AccountOperatorPassword)
                {
                    password.AppendChar(x);
                }
                string onmicrosoftemail = Email.ToLower().Replace("mail.com", "mail.onmicrosoft.com");
                PSCredential PSCredential = new PSCredential(userName, password);
                WSManConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(ServerUri), SchemaUri, PSCredential);
                ConnectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
                Runspace RemoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ConnectionInfo);
                PowerShell RemotePowerShell = PowerShell.Create();
                RemotePowerShell.AddCommand("Enable-RemoteMailbox");
                RemotePowerShell.AddParameter("Identity", samAccount);
                RemotePowerShell.AddParameter("RemoteRoutingAddress", onmicrosoftemail);
                // Open the remote runspace on the server.
                RemoteRunspace.Open();
                // Associate the runspace with the Exchange Management Shell.
                RemotePowerShell.Runspace = RemoteRunspace;
                var result = RemotePowerShell.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject RSLT in result)
                {
                    back += RSLT.ToString();
                }
                RemoteRunspace.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return back;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution for anyone have the same problem

1. create user as a member of (Recipient Management group)
2. IIS change (for exchange server)
   navigate to IIS Manager | Default Website | PowerShell
   Change the physical path from: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\PowerShell
   to: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\PowerShell
3. After the change: IISRESET

and it will work fine

Comment: We do have the same problem in our environment. Can you give us a more precise explanation of the problem and why this configuration change does help?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make sure Windows PowerShell is enabled for remoting via (see more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting)):

> Enable-PSRemoting

2.) Make sure the local OS firewall isn´t blocking the requests

3.) Depending on the actions you wish to perform you need to grant some needed rights. For [MS Exchange](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298084(v=exchg.141).aspx):

> Set-User David -RemotePowerShellEnabled $True

***P.S.
For security reasons I would NEVER run a IIS pool as an account with local admin rights as mentioned in your post!***

Comment: PSRemoting is enabled 
RemotePowerShellEnabled also enabled for the user

for the iis pool just for a try i'm not going to make it